# Add fetched data into another object and export it

Tags: reactjs, fetch, next.js

Hi I have some data that I want to fetch from an api and add to another array of objects that also contains some other data. I have to then export this data to access it in another component of my webapp.

Here is the code example:

```
//exportingVal,js file

let exportingVal;
async function getData(){
   const category = await fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds')
                          .then(res => res.json())
                          .then(data => {
                              exportingVal = [
                                  {id:1,
                                   name: data[0].name,
                                   description: 'this is a very beautiful cat'
                                  }
                                  {id:2,
                                   name: data[1].name,
                                   description: 'this is a very beautiful cat'
                                  }
                               ]
})

getData();

export default exportingVal;
```

This however results in undefined. What is another way to get the data into this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//exportingVal,js file

export async function getData() {
    const category = await fetch('https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/breeds');
    const myjson = await category.json();
    const old = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: data[0].name,
            description: 'this is a very beautiful cat',
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: data[1].name,
            description: 'this is a very beautiful cat',
        },
    ];
    const final = [ ...old, ...myjson ];
    return final;
}
```

- In your component :-

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getData } from './utils';
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        getMyData();
        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    const getMyData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await getData();
            setData(res);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };

    console.log(data);

    return <div>{data ? <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 3)}</pre> : null}</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Hey! Thnx! Now if i want to use the result of getData in another component will I have to import it and run the main function there?

Comment: @MariumAli no you can just do the same thing that is done in the main function. so, you have to import the getData() and implement like aman has implemented in the main function.

Comment: @ReyYoung ok so in my component I have now imported getData but i need the results to be rendered as jsx.. i should do that within the main function?

Comment: @MariumAli check the updated answer of aman. And if don't want that rendered result then you can check here as well 
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html